# Priority wise Solr Search

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have integrated Solr with my dot NET MVC application. I have used StandardTokenizerFactory tokenizer.

Now, I am having products containing **black** word as well as containing **blackberry** with black color. Now if I search with keyword **black berry black** it gives me result which contain only black word first. I want result first which contain blackberry then the result which only contain black word.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you have issue with synonyms. If you search **black berry black** solr will try to found documents which contains words **black** and **berry**. But in your document does't have such word, it contains **blackberry**. To solve this issue you need configure solr to use multi term synonyms. You can read how to do this  at following [lucidworks blogpost](http://lucidworks.com/blog/2014/07/12/solution-for-multi-term-synonyms-in-lucenesolr-using-the-auto-phrasing-tokenfilter/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will go through this document.